# android-maven-plugin: deploy method that does not delete SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, proguard

I built an android project that set up with android-maven-plugin. When I execute android:deploy and run the program, SharedPreferences always initialized.

Is there a way to deploy my project to AVD without deleting SharedPreferences storage?

P.S.

I use Intellij IDEA and noticed that its [native android run/debug support](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/running-and-debugging-android-applications.html) does not delete SharedPreferences. However, after I add [scala support](https://github.com/rohansingh/android-scala-test) on my project, IDE reports "Too many methods: 112423; max is 65536" error when I run the application. Perhaps it is due to lack of proguard preprocessing. If there are a way to apply proguard before run the android app with Intellij IDEA android support, it would be an equally effective solution.

Comment: Using standard ADB deploy without deleting preferences is given by `adb -s DEVICESERIALCODE install -r APPLICATION.apk` I suspect your deploy script should have this parameter as shell switch. Maybe try goal `android:run`

Comment: @pocorall did you resolve the issue with Scala and too many methods? If so - how did you do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Marek Thanks for a clue. I will dig about it!

Comment: @jdevelop unfortunately, I did not solved this problem :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your app is being uninstalled before being reinstalled again - this would cause you to lose your SharedPreferences values. This can be controlled with the Android Maven plugin parameter [undeployBeforeDeploy](http://jayway.github.io/maven-android-plugin/deploy-mojo.html#undeployBeforeDeploy).

I just tried to create a Maven project with the [android-quickstart](http://stand.spree.de/wiki_details_maven_archetypes) archetype and found that it automatically added the following line to my POM:

```
<undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
```

Try to set this to false and try again.

If you have it set to true, it prints this line in the console when you run `mvn android:deploy`:

```
[INFO] Successfully uninstalled [package] from [device]
```